# Android Cocos2DX using C++ in Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have used Eclipse Helios 3.6.1 for Java development. I wanted to start C++ development in the same IDE so I installed **Autotools Support For CDT, C/C++ Development Tools, C/C++ Library API Documentation Hover Help plugins**.
I have included **#include "cocos2d.h"** in my **HelloWorldScene.h** file now when writing the below statement
 `cocos2d::CCSprite * ccSprite;` 
I am not getting auto completion bar(template proposals) on writing like coco and pressing **Ctrl + Space** from my keyboard. What can be the problem?
This might help you solve my problem. Please check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmC8a.png). This is what I got after clicking Right Click Project -> Index -> Search for Unresolved Index. But I have added all includes check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujvMs.png). I think this is causing problem in Content Assist. What should I do in this case? Inclusion seems proper.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you have included the path to Cocos2d-x headers folder in your project properties? If not right click on your project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes tab > Add > $PATH_TO_YOUR_COCOS2DX/cocos2dx/include where you must replace $PATH_TO_YOUR_COCOS2DX by the actual absolute path to where you downloaded the cocos2dx framework.

PS: You should upgrade your eclipse to Juno as well, Helios is a bit old now :)

Comment: i done it but did not work for me,i hv Helios Service Release 2,i will try with linux then might be possible

Answer (score 1):

Sorry dont download eclipse juno actually. It comes with a new tool for discovery options (huge joke) that results in a lot of "type could not be resolved". Many people have problems with that including myself as you can see there [Eclipse Juno's "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." symbol scanner for CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125703/eclipse-junos-preprocessor-include-paths-macros-etc-symbol-scanner-for-cdt) It messes all my includes, therefore im going back to indigo.