# Native c++ with Android on Eclipse - gives error on stdlib but works

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, debugging

I have been building my android app in an android eclipse environment. Building my c++ code and compiling it independantly with ndk-build. That works fine.

I need to debug a sigsegv error which is thrown by logcat all of a sudden.

So I switched the project in eclipse to 'add native code in android'. Now it debugs my c++ code, but gives me an error each time I use any of the std components, such as vector and so I cannot run the code since it contains errors.

The project ran fine on the previous config. I added a lib for std support I believe.

Any idea on how I can properly debug my native code?

Thank you for the help

UPDATE
I totally reinstalled my sdk, eclipse (juno this time) and all plugings. No change. The error checking does not recognise java and std related stuff:

```
#include <jni.h>
using namespace std;
```

is underlined in red.

The rest of c++ is recognised properly.

UPDATE2

When I add ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include to Paths and Includes, The java statements are already included. Net the vectors yet, I also tried to add ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport but it did not fix the vector problem yet. If error checking is disabled, the project compiles and if I make a synthax error, the compiler warns me. That is ok for me.

Comment: Are you getting **code-assistance and auto error checking** feature while writing C++ code in eclipse?

Comment: @25061987 Yes, I am getting code-assistance and error checking in c++. The problem is that the code-checking does not recognise elements from java (#include <jni.h>) and std (using namespace std;) The rest works fine. I think it could have something to do with the fact that I had to add stlport to my application.mk file and the eclipse builder is not seeing this.

Comment: I am using Cocos2D-X C++ include in my Java project. And converting my java project to C++ project. When I am using cocos2D-X class then writing half class name and pressing **Ctrl + Space** does not helping to complete class and so it does not tell me the methods I can use with a particular object type. It is like when we use external .jar in our java project it provides intellisense. Do you know what can be the problem? Or are you facing the same problem?

Comment: @25061987 No, this works fine in my project. Eclipse just falls over std. I think this should be a separate question, but you should probably convert your project to c++.

Comment: I have added this as separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716052/android-cocos2dx-using-c-in-eclipse-helios). I have also converted android project to C++. If you find anything wrong feel free to edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You, probably, can, first, disable errors in `Project Properties|C/C++ General|Code Analysis` so your project compiles.

You can then check if the include paths in `Project Properties|C/C++ General|Paths and Symbols` are correct.

I have also heard that updating the ADT plugin may help.

Comment: @Alex Thanks. I had added my ndk-build dir to PATH (system). And in Project Properties -> c++ compiler, I added the full path to ndk-build. HOWEVER, if I start up eclipse from command line, I do get a message "Unable to find full path for "ndk-build"". If add the ndk-build path to paths and symbols as you suggest, it does not yet make a difference, I still get the message.

Comment: @dorien Mine include path is C:\android-ndk-r8\platforms\android-8\arch-arm\usr\include under Paths and Symbols|Includes|GNU C++ and I am able to start Eclipse from the command line all right. Perhaps you need an absolute path in there?

Comment: Thanks. I changed my path to platforms/android-4/arch/arm/usr/include.  Command start works (as before) but still lists "Unable to find full path for "ndk-build"". Debugging still doesn't work and vectors are still marked in red. I read here [link]http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/ [/link] that you cannot debug in c++, perhaps it's just not possible?

Comment: @dorien Debugging is possible but the setup is painful. It's described in detail (for example) in Android NDK Beginner's Guide http://www.wowebook.be/book/android-ndk-beginners-guide/#

Comment: I got the book, it looks nice. I will give it a try and keep you posted.

Comment: @Alex: I am not able to get **code-assitence** while programming in eclipse Helios? i.e. Suppose you want to type `cocos2d::CCSprite * _ship;`. After writing **coc** and pressing **Ctrl + Space** are you getting code assist? I am not getting this feature I used to have this feature while programming in **Java**. What can be the problem? I have configured all **Paths and Symbols(includes)**.

Comment: @Alex: I did a totally new setup, following each step op the book you recommended, but no change. Enabling the code analysis is a good temporary solution, but that also disables error checking if you program c++, which is kinda useful. I will dive into the debugging chapter now.

Comment: I also added yourdir/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport to the paths and libs. When error checking is disabled, the project compiles. And if I make a c++ synthax error, the compiler stopt me. That is enough functionality for me, but still seems to be kind of strange to set it up like that. Still working on the debugger!