# Changing an Android app's folder name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, renaming

I have an android app (with jni, ndk). And I want to change its name. I have changed the package name successfully, and the title of the app in strings.xml like suggested in other posts on this forum.

But the .apk file still has the old name. I am guessing this is because the main folder still has the old name. If I change the foldername in eclipse and "update references". I get the following error.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'NewName'.
Internal error building project NewName configuration Default
java.lang.NullPointerException
Internal error building project NewName configuration Default
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So I am guessing it confuses the ndk-build. If I look at the project's properties for C++, everything looks normal (I think). The build path is ${workspace_loc:/NewName}.

Any ideas on what to check?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

Ok, the ndk-build command works fine from command line. But if I only compile the native c++ from eclipse it gives me the error. I am guessing that something in the project's properties is wrong...

When I disable code checking, the project runs fine. The c++ also seems to be stuck on std commands. Although I have added three libraries to my path, as described here [Native c++ with Android on Eclipse - gives error on stdlib but works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723210/native-c-with-android-on-eclipse-gives-error-on-stdlib-but-works) And they are defined as absolute paths, like this /home/dorien/workspace2/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport

Comment: It may be a silly question, but did you update the manifest.xml file ?

Comment: Yes, AndroidManifest.xml is updated

Comment: Be aware that if the app is already available for users on the Google Play and you change the package name, users that have the app installed won't see the update (it's considered a new app). For more info http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I just wanted to make it available on Play. That is why I wanted to set the right name :-)

Comment: @dorien So your issue was fixed, please close it or add answer and mark.

Comment: The issue was not fixed, as I want to keep code checking enabled.

Comment: Are you using the latest ADT bundle, or you have enabled Adnroid native build manually on an existing instance of Eclipse?