# Debugging android jni code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

How can i debug jni code of my android application in idea?

I've built jni code with ndk-build and flag -NDK_DEBUG=1, but this didn't helped. Idea didn't fall in my breakpoints in c++ code.

I also tried to create "Remote" debug with default params and run it. But nothing happened.

Can anyone help ? Step by step manual or something would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IntelliJ supports C++ development, so you cannot debug your C code inside IntelliJ as far as I know. It would be great if it did though... You can set up some debugging environmnet for jni in eclipse, but it's quite complicated.

According to a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723210/native-c-with-android-on-eclipse-gives-error-on-stdlib-but-works) the setup in eclipse is described in detail (for example) in [Android NDK Beginner's Guide](http://wowebook.be/book/android-ndk-beginners-guide/#)