# IntelliJ JNI debugging

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have an android application which does some real time sound processing. Since this task is time critical, I wrote the code that does the processing in C++, the rest of the application is Java. Android Studio supports JNI debugging no questions asked which made it easy for me to write the code. Then, I left the code alone and decided in the meanwhile to get rid of Android Studio and to use IntelliJ instead.

Now, I had an issue in the native code and wanted to debug the C++ code, when I suddenly realized that I was unable to set breakpoints in the C++ code.

I also tried to set a breakpoint in the java code just before the native call and hoped that by hitting "Step in" it would go inside the native code but instead, InteliJ just skipped over it.

Also, the run configuration with dual debugging enabled (which I created in Android Studio back then) does not seem to work (Android Studio used to load a ton of libraries when launching the native debugger, IntelliJ does not do that).

This seems odd to me, as - according to JetBrain's official blogpost - IntelliJ has all of Android Studio's features except for the project setup wizard. What am I missing here?

Btw I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607007/debugging-android-jni-code-in-intellij-idea) but its answers are outdated.

Comment: How are you building the c++ library? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I use gradle's `externalNativeBuild` target

Comment: And I edited the files with Android Studio as Android Studio also supports C++ editing.

Comment: Right, well one way you can debug your DLL (if you are on Windows) would be to build the DLL in debug mode and attach the Visual Studio debugger to your Java process. But without a VS build this solution doesn't apply

Comment: As far as I understood the jni build process, gradle calls clang which in turn compiles the C++ to `libSomething.so`.

Comment: But anyway, how do you suggest to compile/debug the JNI code in VS?

Comment: Well, assuming you already have a VS build that produces you DLL, VS can be attached to the process (you need the PID of the running process), breakpoints can be inserted from VS. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: I used that a while ago to debug the Quantlib (c++)  while being called via JNI, VS is quite handy

Comment: But I see Android Studio uses http://lldb.llvm.org/ , maybe you can look for help on how to use this other debugger

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but I don't think that this is possible. I am talking about an android application which runs on my android phone, not on my computer. I can debug the java code through USB and in Android Studio, I used to be able to do the same with C++. But since it's not running on my machine, there's no java process which VS could attach to

Comment: Well if you need to debug the interaction of the android app and the c++ library, while running on your phone, then porting all back to Android Studio seems the only choice (and AS is very powerful in that respect). A lighter approach to debugging would be to use the same c++ library in a different Java application (if you can feed the library the same data and you can disregard the actual interaction with the phone). Anyway.. good luck :)

Comment: I wanted to avoid having Android Studio and IntelliJ installed side-by-side as they are essentially the same piece of software. But as there seems to be no better solution, I guess I will have to go back to AS. So much for "Android Studio and IntelliJ are equivalent except for the project setup wizard" :/

Comment: If you mind to rephrase your comments as an answer @Daniele, I would mark it as the solution as it might solve the issue for some folks.